# Ionic: how to programmatically update ion-toggle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

this has been bugging me for ages but I can't figure out how to programmatically change an ion-toggle value.

My toggle starts as on. When someone slides it off, I popup a confirmation. If they cancel the confirmation, I want to reset the toggle back to where it was before:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="twitterConnection" ng-change="twitterConnectionChange()">Twitter</ion-toggle>

$ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                template: 'Are you sure you want to disconnect this account?'
            }).then(function(res) {
                if(res) {
                    delete $window.localStorage.twitterToken;
                    delete $rootScope.user.twitterID;
                }
                else {
                    $scope.twitterConnection = true;
                }
            });
```

I've tried wrapping the $scope.twitterConnection = true; line in $apply, but that gives the "digest already in progress" error. I've tried wrapping it in $timeout, but nothing happens. I'm a relative beginner so all help appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/Shiftlemac/pen/pjZRbP

Comment: What is in your `twitterConnectionChange()` function?

Comment: The $ionicPopup.confirm(...) logic

Comment: can you provide an jsfiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer courtesy of the ionic forum:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/programmatic-updating-of-ion-toggle-not-working/36155/2?u=shiftlemac

Essentially I needed to use the ng-checked attribute of the ion-toggle and set up the twitterConnection variable as an object as per this kind gentleman's codepen: http://codepen.io/DaDanny/pen/xwJdLr

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="twitterConnection.checked" ng-change="twitterConnectionChange()" ng-checked="twitterConnection.checked">Twitter</ion-toggle>

$scope.twitterConnection = {
    checked: true,
    text: 'Twitter' }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend you to do, is the following:

Create the function, which will be responsible for changing the value of the toggle.

So, in your case it will be:

```
$ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                template: 'Are you sure you want to disconnect this account?'
            }).then(function(res) {
                if(res) {
                    delete $window.localStorage.twitterToken;
                    delete $rootScope.user.twitterID;
                    $scope.twitterConnectionToggleOn();
                }
                else {
                    $scope.twitterConnectionToggleOff();
                }
            });
```

and

```
    $scope.twitterConnectionToggleOff = function(){
        $scope.twitterConnection = false;
    }
    $scope.twitterConnectionToggleOn = function(){
        $scope.twitterConnection = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first update state on your components like $scope.twitterConnection = true; or $scope.twitterConnection = false ; final run $scope.$apply(); finish

sorry my bad english